# "Error: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: role "postgres" does not exist" en Github Actions

Tags: django, github-actions

tengo una aplicación Django donde estoy implementando Github Actions y para ello he creado el fichero .github/workflows/django.yml. El fichero es el siguiente:

```
name: Python application

 on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.8
    env:
      POSTGRES_USER: decide
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: decide
      POSTGRES_DB: decide
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    # needed because the postgres container does not provide a healthcheck
    options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- name: Set up Python 3.8
  uses: actions/setup-python@v1
  with:
    python-version: 3.8
- name: psycopg2 prerequisites
  run: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install codacy-coverage
- name: Run migrations
  run: cd decide;python manage.py makemigrations;python manage.py migrate
- name: Run tests     
  run: cd decide;coverage run --branch --source=. ./manage.py test --keepdb; coverage xml;
- name: Codacy Coverage Reporter
  uses: codacy/codacy-coverage-reporter-action@v1.1.0
  with:
      project-token: ${{ secrets.CODACY_PROJECT_TOKEN }}
      coverage-reports: decide/coverage.xml
deploy:
needs: build
if: ${{github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'}}
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12 # This is the action
  with:
      heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
      heroku_app_name: "xxx"
      heroku_email: "xxx"
```

Perdonad los espacios pero se copia mal desde vs-code.
El problema surge al lanzarse el build dado que, después de correr el comando "coverage run --branch --source=. ./manage.py test --keepdb" y mostrado que los tests han funcionado correctamente, me muestra el error: **Error: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: role "postgres" does not exist**
He buscado por mil sitios pero no consigo dar con el error. He mirado dentro de psql a ver si está el usuario postgres con todos los privilegios y está en mi bd en local pero, puede ser por no entender del todo como funciona, no lo captura en Github Actions.
¿Alguna sugerencia de por qué puede ser?
Gracias de antemano.